# How to select the last inserted records in a table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, version, range, date-range

I know that have operator `VERSIONS BETWEEN TIMESTAMP MINVALUE AND MAXVALUE`, but it's don't work correct. Query

```
SELECT VERSIONS_ENDTIME, VERSIONS_OPERATION FROM mytable VERSIONS BETWEEN TIMESTAMP MINVALUE AND MAXVALUE
```

return empty feilds: `VERSIONS_ENDTIME` and `VERSIONS_OPERATION`.

[image]

**Maybe have another methods for select the last inserted records in a table from the last week?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use [Flashback Queries](http://psoug.org/reference/flash_query.html), but this kind of approach is not feasible for a production system. This approach should be used for recovery or administrational queries.

Under normal circumstances, you should have some other kind of method for detecting when a row was inserted, for example you can add a `date` column in your table and populate it with `SYSDATE` on each `insert`.

Comment: I need it just to administrative tasks.